# Enable disabled elements per console

Tags: jquery, html, console, attributes

for one of my screens I am using the HTML **disabled** attribute foreach element (select, button, input) per jQuery to avoid the user to change a form which he is seeing on the screen. This way I am giving the user a read-only capability.

Now I am wondering. Is it possible to enable the disabled elements per console/browser dev tools? Need to know that if my implementation is secure to prevent the user from activating and modifying the form.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a form with a disabled <input type="submit"> be hacked to submit anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358484/can-a-form-with-a-disabled-input-type-submit-be-hacked-to-submit-anyway)